# JetBrains IDEs - How To Prevent IDE From Changing "Class" Attribute To "ClassName" In React Projects On Copy And Paste?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, rubymine

I work on a React project with my JetBrains IDE and most of the elements in my project are React components.  I do however use the Ionic Icons library and when I need to insert an icon into my component, I use something like:

`<ion-icon class="icon" name="chevron-forward-outline"/>`

Since the Ionic elements are not React components, it uses the `class` attribute as opposed to the `className` attribute.  Every time I copy and paste an Ionic element like the one above, my JetBrains IDE automatically changes the `class` attribute to `className`.

How do I prevent the IDE from doing this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

please try disabling **Convert HTML when pasting into JSX files (convert attributes, close single tags)** in **Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys | JavaScript**

Comment: I'm editing a normal .js file, how do I say to the editor that is not a JSX one?

Comment: If you are using JSX in your code, it's a JSX file regardless of extension

Comment: It is now called "Convert HTML when pasting into JSX files (convert attributes, close single tags)"